# tk.h not found while building KwWidget

Tags: compilation, tcl, tk-toolkit

Following errors occurred while building KWWidget:

```
3>vtkKWApplicationTcl.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWTkTreeCtrlInit.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>tkShape.cpp
3>..\KWWidgets-HEAD-cvs\Utilities\tkdnd\win\tkShape.cpp(13) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Tcl_Obj'
3>..\KWWidgets-HEAD-cvs\Utilities\tkdnd\win\tkShape.cpp(16) : error C2065: 'objv' : undeclared identifier
3>..\KWWidgets-HEAD-cvs\Utilities\tkdnd\win\tkShape.cpp(16) : error C3861: 'Tcl_WrongNumArgs': identifier not found
3>..\KWWidgets-HEAD-cvs\Utilities\tkdnd\win\tkShape.cpp(24) : error C3861: 'Tcl_CreateObjCommand': identifier not found
3>..\KWWidgets-HEAD-cvs\Utilities\tkdnd\win\tkShape.cpp(27) : error C3861: 'Tcl_PkgProvide': identifier not found
3>tkOleDND.cpp
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>OleDND.cpp
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWTkDnDInit.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>tkDNDBind.cpp
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>tkDND.cpp
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWTkconInit.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWTablelistInit.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWBWidgetsInit.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWWidgetsInitializeCommand.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWSimpleAnimationWidget.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWSelectionFrameLayoutManager.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWRenderWidget.cxx
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(353) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(353) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(353) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(353) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(353) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(389) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'LPTCH'
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(389) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(389) : error C2378: 'LPCH' : redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef
3>        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(353) : see declaration of 'LPCH'
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(389) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(389) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(398) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(398) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(398) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(399) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(399) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(399) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winbase.h(3422) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winbase.h(3422) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winbase.h(3422) : error C2040: 'LPCH' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winbase.h(3425) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winbase.h(3447) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NewEnvironment'
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winbase.h(3447) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winbase.h(3447) : error C2491: 'SetEnvironmentStringsA' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winbase.h(3447) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'BOOL'
3>        There is no context in which this conversion is possible
3>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winbase.h(3447) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
3>Compiling...
3>vtkKWPresetSelector.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWPopupButton.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWOptionDataBase.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWObject.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
3>vtkKWMultiColumnList.cxx
3>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
.
.
24>Linking...
24>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\bin\Debug\KWWidgets.lib'
24>Build log was saved at "file://d:\KWWidget\bin\Utilities\KWConvertImageToHeader.dir\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
24>KWConvertImageToHeader - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
25>------ Build started: Project: KWFileBrowserDialogExample, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
25>Compiling...
25>KWFileBrowserDialogExample.cxx
25>D:\VTK\src\Common\vtkTk.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tk.h': No such file or directory
25>Build log was saved at "file://d:\KWWidget\bin\Examples\Cxx\FileBrowserDialog\KWFileBrowserDialogExample.dir\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
25>KWFileBrowserDialogExample - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
26>------ Skipped Build: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
26>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 20 failed, 3 up-to-date, 6 skipped ==========
```

I have installed ActiveTcl8.5.13.0.296436-win32-ix86-threaded and TclDevKit5.3.0.295349-win32-ix86-threaded but couldn't found tk.h please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveTcl, while it does include the runtime libraries, omits the header files for both the Tcl and Tk libraries. It probably also omits the link libraries (but I'm not sure about that; I'm not on the right platform to check). To build anything, you'll probably need to get hold of [the source distributions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Tcl/8.5.13/) for Tcl and Tk from SourceForge (picking 8.5.13 to match your ActiveTcl distribution) and build them yourself. However, once you've built, you might be able to run against the ActiveTcl dynamic libraries (especially if you've built the code to use the stubbed API).

Note that ActiveTcl is, apart from the extra packages and tools it supplies, a conventional Tcl distribution.

Comment: can you please explain how to build tcl/tk for windows I tried this[link](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/compile.html) but got error:

Comment: hey I did a silly mistake. tcl.h and tk.h both are present at include directory. I just configured project properties and added path to Additional Include Directories and problem solved.